# Failed to load dynlib/dll for tls-client-64.dll

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\garfi\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI200362\tls_client\dependencies\tls-client-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "tls_client\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "tls_client\sessions.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "tls_client\cffi.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 55, in __init__
pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\garfi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI200362\\tls_client/dependencies/tls-client-64.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[4520] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

How can I make this work?
None of the answers on stackoverflow help so i came here for a fix.
This happens with pyinstaller, whenever i try to freeze it with auto-py-to-exe, py2exe, or any other python to executable script, this error pops out or a different dll is missing.
How can i make sure that all dlls are available?
Here's a list of my imports:
import fade
import requests
import re
import sys
import time
import aiohttp
import json
import whois
import bs4
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
import tls_client
import functools
import pystyle
import threading
import urllib3
import ssl
import typing
import subprocess
import logging
import qrcode